# Can't copy text out of web page

Tags: firefox, copy-paste

I can't copy text out of some web pages. I assume this is because the page somehow disables the Ctrl-C key.

I tried to use the Developer Web Console in Firefox and that did not work either. Here is a screen shot:

[image: copy problem]

In the screen shot above, you can see I am trying to copy the text in a paragraph span which I have isolated in the Inspector (the text begins "65 Market Street..."). Nevertheless, when I open up the context menu, copying is grayed out and disabled, as you can see.

How can I copy the text?

Comment: You refer to http://www.greenlightre.ky right? For me, right-click works fine :/

Comment: I just discovered: Make sure, you select the element which contains the text, not the text itself.